# Based on vector of strings extract string from data.table column into new column

Tags: r

in a data.table I have a column with company names that sometimes include the city of that company. Based on a vector of all existing cities I would like to detect if a city name is part of the company name and if yes extract the city into a new column. I used a for loop that loops trough every row of my data.table over all cities within my vector of cities in R. This takes a very long time. Is there a way I can vectorize this operation to make it more efficient computationally.

| Company_name | Location |
| --- | --- |
| Company 1 Berlin Gmbh. | NA |
| Dresden Company 2 Gmbh. | NA |
| Company 3 in Hamburg | NA |
| Company 4 Ldt | NA |

| Company_name | Location |
| --- | --- |
| Company 1 Berlin Gmbh. | Berlin |
| Dresden Company 2 Gmbh. | Dresden |
| Company 3 in Hamburg | Hamburg |
| Company 4 Ldt | NA |

Comment: Greetings! Instead of sharing a table, it would make things easier if people could easily work with the data you have. Please provide a reproducible dataset by providing the `dput` or subset of your data. Here is a guide for doing so: https://youtu.be/3EID3P1oisg

Answer (score 2):

```
df[, city:=stringr::str_extract(Company, paste0(cities,collapse = "|"))]
```

OR

```
# this also works
df[, city:=cities[sapply(cities, \(x) grepl(x,Company))], by=1:nrow(df)]
```

Output:

```
                   Company    city
1:  Company 1 Berlin Gmbh.  Berlin
2: Dresden Company 2 Gmbh. Dresden
3:    Company 3 in Hamburg Hamburg
4:           Company 4 Ldt    <NA>
```

Input:

```
library(data.table)
df =data.table(
  Company = c(
  "Company 1 Berlin Gmbh.", 
  "Dresden Company 2 Gmbh.",
  "Company 3 in Hamburg",
  "Company 4 Ldt")
)
cities = c('Berlin','Dresden','Hamburg')
```

Comment: Great answer! I posted a related question if you are interested: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74161558/wrapping-a-string-extract-function-in-an-ifelse-statement