# Wrapping a string extract function in an ifelse statement

Tags: r, if-statement, stringr, stringi

The question below is an extension of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74135095/adding-a-column-to-the-data-that-looks-for-a-list-of-words-and-adds-them-if-foun).

## Example data

I have example data as follows:

```
library(data.table)
example_dat <- fread("var_nam description
      some_var this_is_some_var_kg
      other_var this_is_meters_for_another_var
      extra_var the_price_of_apples
      another_var cost_of_goods_sold")
example_dat$description  <- gsub("_", " ", example_dat$description)

       var_nam                    description
1:    some_var            this is some var kg
2:   other_var this is meters for another var
3:   extra_var            the price of apples
4: another_var             cost of goods sold

vector_of_units <- c("kg", "meters", "var")
```

## Previous solutions

I first asked how to create a separate column in this data which looks for certain units listed in a vector (`vector_of_units`). One option is to [use this answer by maydin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74135271/8071608). Which gets out all matches.

```
library(tidyverse)
setDT(example_dat)[, unit :=    unlist(lapply(example_dat$description,function(x) 
                    paste0(vector_of_units[str_detect(x,vector_of_units)],
                    collapse = ",")))]

       var_nam                    description       unit
1:    some_var            this is some var Kg     kg,var
2:   other_var this is meters for another var meters,var
3:   extra_var            the Price of apples           
4: another_var             cost of goods sold
```

I also found [this answer by langtang](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71280592/8071608), which gets out the first match (which is actually preferable in my situation):

```
example_dat[, unit:=stringr::str_extract(description, paste0(vector_of_units,collapse = "|"))]

       var_nam                    description   unit
1:    some_var            this is some var kg    var
2:   other_var this is meters for another var meters
3:   extra_var            the price of apples   <NA>
4: another_var             cost of goods sold   <NA>
```

[Based on vector of strings extract string from data.table column into new column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71280466/based-on-vector-of-strings-extract-string-from-data-table-column-into-new-column)

## More flexibility with an ifelse statement

I would however like to have a little more flexibility.

Firstly, I would like to supply a vector of matches and a vector for pasting separately, so that I can change the hits in to something else:

```
vector_of_units_in <- c("kg", "meters", "var")
vector_of_units_out <- c("kilogram", "meters", "variable")

vector_of_units_euro <- c("cost", "price")
vector_of_units_euro_out <- "euro"
```

Secondly, I would like to be able to choose what happens when there is no hit. For example, when applying the solution by langtang, I want it to not overwrite the first variables with `NA`.

I have been trying to mess around with langtang's solution:

```
setDT(example_dat)[, unit := ifelse(!is.na(stringr::str_extract(description, vector_of_units_in)), paste0(vector_of_units_out, collapse = "|"), NA)]

# NA has been replaced by unit, so that it is not overwritten in case of no match
setDT(example_dat)[, unit := ifelse(!is.na(stringr::str_extract(description, vector_of_units_euro)), paste0(vector_of_units_euro_out, collapse = "|"), unit)]
```

But I end with this:

```
       var_nam                    description                     unit
1:    some_var            this is some var kg kilogram|meters|variable
2:   other_var this is meters for another var kilogram|meters|variable
3:   extra_var            the price of apples                     <NA>
4: another_var             cost of goods sold                     <NA>
```

How should I write this syntax?

## Desired output

```
       var_nam                    description       unit
1:    some_var            this is some var Kg     kilogram
2:   other_var this is meters for another var     meters
3:   extra_var            the Price of apples     euro      
4: another_var             cost of goods sold     euro
```

Comment: Hello, the error is because you're passing four arguments to `ifelse`, which takes only three. I cant' see where `naam_nl` comes from.

Comment: @RicVillalba Thank you for pointing out the error, I get an empty unit column now however..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a named units vector and `Vectorize` `grep` for `outer`. In a case handling `if` no matches found, we can throw `NA`.

```
units <- c(kilogram="kg", meters="meters", euro="cost", euro="price", variable='var')

dat[, unit:=apply(outer(units, description, Vectorize(grepl)), 2, \(x) 
                  if (any(x)) names(which(x)) else NA)]
dat
# var_nam                    description              unit
# 1:    some_var            this is some var kg kilogram,variable
# 2:    some_var                   this is some                NA
# 3:   other_var this is meters for another var   meters,variable
# 4:   extra_var            the price of apples              euro
# 5: another_var             cost of goods sold              euro
```

---

*Data:*

```
dat <- structure(list(var_nam = c("some_var", "some_var", "other_var", 
"extra_var", "another_var"), description = c("this is some var kg", 
"this is some var", "this is meters for another var", "the price of apples", 
"cost of goods sold")), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x558a7b025230>)
```

Comment: @Tom `description`, sorry.

Comment: Thanks jay, on my actual data, I am getting a recycle warning (probably because not all rows have a hit.. `Supplied 12 items to be assigned to 939 items of column 'unit'. If you wish to 'recycle' the RHS please use rep() to make this intent clear to readers of your code.` Would you kow how I can solve that?

Comment: Thanks again, I have accepted your answer. Did you intend for the solution to be a column with vector/list inside?

Comment: @Tom Yes, to take care of multiple matches. It's hard to predict which is the valid match, but in a second step you can easily use `dat[, unit:=sapply(unit, `[`, 1)]` for first match, or  e.g. `dat[, unit:=mapply(`[`, dat$unit, c(2, 1, 2, 1, 1))]` for individual matches, gets a vector then.

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't tag `data.table` explicitly, you may be open to a `tidyverse`  solution as well:

First define a vector of units you want to match:

```
units_to_match <- c("kg", "meters", "cost", "price")
```

Then define a vector with the replacements:

```
units_to_replace <- setNames(c("kilogram", "meters", "euro", "euro"),
                             c("kg", "meters", "cost", "price"))
```

Now first extract the matches using `str_extract_all` and then replace them using `str_replace_all`:

```
library(tidyverse)    
example_dat %>%
  mutate(unit = str_extract_all(description, str_c(units_to_match, collapse = "|")),
         unit = str_replace_all(unit, units_to_replace))
       var_nam                    description     unit
1:    some_var            this_is_some_var_kg kilogram
2:   other_var this_is_meters_for_another_var   meters
3:   extra_var            the_price_of_apples     euro
4: another_var             cost_of_goods_sold     euro
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer Chris. I did indeed nog tag data.table explicityly. When applying your solution I get the error: `Warning message:
Problem while computing unit = str_replace_all(unit, units_to_replace).
ℹ argument is not an atomic vector; coercing ` Do you have any clue when this might happen?

Comment: It works for me with the data you posted: `example_dat <- fread("var_nam description
      some_var this_is_some_var_kg
      other_var this_is_meters_for_another_var
      extra_var the_price_of_apples
      another_var cost_of_goods_sold")`

Comment: It does, that is also why I upvoted. I just hoped that you perhaps had an idea of when such an error could occur.

Comment: If you show me the data on which you got the error I could perhaps tell you ...